# How can i rewrite this as

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

so i want open this large file as rb with "file:" thing infront of it so i can use request.post to upload a video sooo  how can i rewrite this line

```
file = {'file': open(file_path, 'rb')}
```

as

```
with {'file': open("somefile.txt")} as f:
```

while keeping {'file': }

this is orgnial code

```
def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=100000000): #Change Chunk Size According To Your Internet Speed
    """Generator to read a file piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 1k."""
    while True:
        data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data
        
# Upload
def upload(login, key, file_path):
    sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256()
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        for byte_block in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            sha256_hash.update(byte_block)
        sha256 = sha256_hash.hexdigest()
    url = f'https://api.streamtape.com/file/ul?login={login}&key={key}&sha256={sha256}'
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    upload_url = data['result']['url']
    #file = {'file': open(file_path, 'rb')}
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file_obj:
        for file_chunk in read_in_chunks(file_obj):
                print("uploading")
                upload_request = requests.post(upload_url, data=file_chunk)
    
    #upload_request = requests.post(upload_url, files=file)
    upload_response = upload_request.json()
    return upload_response
```

it's working but it's not uploading the file to api as it doesnot have th " { file: } "
here

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as file_obj:
    for file_chunk in read_in_chunks(file_obj):
            print("uploading")
            upload_request = requests.post(upload_url, data=file_chunk)
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO, please format the original code inside` \``` ` blocks. since it is python is is almost impossible to reproduce the delimitation correctly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you wanted to give requests.post a dictionary with the key `'file'` for its `data` argument. You can just do that like this:

`upload_request = requests.post(upload_url, data={'file': file_chunk})`

Comment: i used that cammand but it did not upload the file soo this this is file chunk is binary data of that mp4 file and that cammand file adds "file" infront of it but i need too add "file" in front of file path soo is there a way i can do this ``    file = {'file': file_path}
    with open(file, 'rb') as file_obj:
        for file_chunk in read_in_chunks(file_obj):
``

Comment: You mean you want the file path that python opens to be, for example, `file/something/somefile.mp4` instead of `/something/somefile.mp4`?

Comment: noo broo soo see this code is working file = {'file': open(file_path, 'rb')} and uploading the file to server but now i want to upload 2gb file soo it want to chunk down the file right soo i found this code online to chuck     with open(file, 'rb') as file_obj:
but the problem is i don't know how can i add {"file": infront of the file

Comment: In that case (and looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)), I think the above line of code should work for sending 1k chunks at a time. What problem were you getting?

Comment: well it's uploading the chunks but not to the server.....

Comment: Where is it uploading the chunks to then?